# Is encrypting specific connections the same as mutual authentication?

Tags: sql-server, security, amazon-rds

I am trying to establish a secure connection to a SQL Server database over the internet. In the link below a configuration "Encrypting Specific Connections" is described:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Concepts.General.SSL.Using.html

I have read elsewhere that mutual authentication (server authenticating the client based on certificate) is not supported by SQL Server. Is the described configuration equivalent to mutual authentication or something completely else?

If it is something else, are there other security features of RDS (apart from ip whitelisting) that can increase security over username and password?

Edit: The connection will be encrypted, so when i say increase security i mean in the sense that would work as a second factor of authentication.

Comment: The two concepts are completely different. Mutual authentication wouldn't prevent a man-in-the-middle attack, or prevent anyone from capturing the unencrypted data. Mutual authentication is completely useless if someone can simply capture everything

Comment: BTW the proper place to check for SQL Server security features is SQL Server's documentation. There are a lot of features that offer far better security than mutual authentication. Different features protect against different attacks. Mutual authentication would prevent a rogue computer from connecting but .... that's what VPNs are for. Using mutual authentication instead of a VPN *weakens* security.

Comment: There are other, more powerful features too. [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) for example encrypts on the client side and never reveals the keys to the server. Even a DBA won't be able to read that data. That's useful if *that's* what you actually want to protect against. Otherwise, a VPN will be a far safer option

Comment: Rogue computer is the relevant case here, so good point about VPN. Thanks.

Comment: A better case would be `What is a database doing on the public internet` ? You can't just leave your database accessible to anyone. Mutual authentication won't protect you from attacks, you need a firewall for this, or a VPN.